# addResourceHandlers not working in spring mvc?

Tags: java, css, spring, spring-mvc

I've created a spring project using maven webapp archetype in intelliJ IDEA. I'm using tomcat plugin and maven plugin. I'm able to run the app on app-name/home path but the css and images are not loading, it is showing simple text and image emoticons.

Inside project I've created ApplicationInitializer class which is fine and ApplicationConfig  which looks like this -

```
package com.test;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.test")
public class ApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("css/**","images/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/css/","classpath:/images/");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

Here's the folder structure-

[image: Structure]

I'm accessing css and images file like below in my jsp file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HPlus</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
Sök
<body>
    // Some div tags
    <img src="images/hpluslogo.svg" alt="Logo - H Plus Sports">
</body>
</html>
```

I've also tied the ApplicationConfig class with the context I've created inside ApplicationInitializer class, which seems fine. Can anybody suggest where I might be wrong.

Comment: Can you share your project structure and files location as a picture in your answer as well?

Answer (score 0):

If using Spring security you can include [this](https://github.com/ajkr195/springbootrocks/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/boot/rocks/config/ConfigWebSecurity.java):

```
httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**").permitAll();
```

For your MVC config, you can use [this](https://github.com/ajkr195/springbootrocks/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/boot/rocks/config/ConfigWebMVC.java):

```
private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
        "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
        "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/"
};
```

Jsp tags may look like [these](https://github.com/ajkr195/springbootrocks/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/fragments/header.jspf):

```
<link href="/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/webjars/popper.js/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```

Also make sure you have css and js folder under static folder in resources like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm not using spring security. I added classpath_resource_locations field in ApplicationConfig class and added those header tags in jsp file but its not working.

Comment: Please see the update. Refer the project structure : `static > css` and `static > js`

Comment: Okay, I had put css and images folder inside /resources/static but it is still not working. Also I'm not really getting what are you suggesting me to do in your answer. I've put directory, ApplicationConfig file above kindly try to answer based on those. Thanks.

Comment: looks like you still missing leading `/` in your config and in your jsp tags.

Comment: I've updated my jsp file in question, I'm using tags like that.